# Cannot submit form with the enter key

Tags: html, submit

I hate to submit this question but I have been unable to find a solution for almost a week now.

```
  <div class="scanform">
  <form action="scanform.php" method="post" id="scanform">
  <p> <label for="Order Number">Order Number:</label>
  <input name="OrderNumber" id="OrderNumber" autofocus="" type="text"><span class="error">*<?php echo $ONErr;?>
  </span></p>
  <input name="submit" value="Submit" type="submit"></form>
  </div>
```

The form works well when I click on the submit button but if I type in the text field and hit enter, the form just reloads.

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

The PHP code:

```
<?php date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto');

$ONErr = "";
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{

  $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "ordertracking");
  if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }
  // Escape user inputs for security
  if (empty($_POST['OrderNumber'])) {
    $ONErr = "OrderNumber is required";
  } else {
    $OrderNumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['OrderNumber']);
    // Attempt insert query execution
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE OrderNumber LIKE '%$OrderNumber' ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: $query - Error: ". mysqli_error($mysqli), E_USER_ERROR);
  } 
  // Close connection
  mysqli_close($link);
}

?>
```

Comment: The code you provided doesn't do much by itself. Consider posting the scanform.php file. That may be where the problem lies.

Comment: i am gonna edit the above response with the php but i it works fine when the submit button is clicked so am sure there is nothing going on there.

Comment: Okay. Well it's a good idea to post all relevant code so we can see everything in play. Maybe you're right, and there's nothing there. Or maybe your overlooking something, and another person can point it out to you.

Comment: php code added. i agree but i dont think i am aware of php code interfering with the html code but am secretly hoping am wrong at the same time. thanks

Comment: There's one thing I don't recognize. It could be my lack of experience with database language, but is this correct `%$OrderNumber`? It shouldn't just be `$OrderNumber`? Again, the `%` sign may have a meaning that I'm just not familiar with.

Comment: its a wildcard for partial matches

Comment: I guess I see what you see: Everything looks good.

Comment: So the form pops the error message when submitted with no text input, but it just reloads when text is submitted with it?

Comment: no, the error message only pops when I click on the submit button with an empty text field. pretty much an enter key in the form result in a page refresh.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said. No text input -> submit button -> error message.

Comment: When you input text, I understand the form reloads, but does the database query execute?

Comment: the database query only execute if i click on submit button (with text in the field). enter in the text field doesnt do anything but reload the page.